MGFs of sum of (Rademacher) independent variables and (hyperbolic/spherical) Pythagorean theorem
Consider a set of iid random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ (distribution to-be-specified later).  For real numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ (with $\sum_{k} a_k^2 < \infty$) define
$$X = a_1 X_1 + a_2 X_2 + \ldots.$$
The moment-generating-function (MGF) $\phi_X(t) = E[e^{t X}]$ of $X$ is of course the product of the individual MGFs:
$$\phi_X(t) = \prod_k E[e^{t a_k X_k}].$$
Consider two cases:
(Normal) $X_k \sim N(0,1)$ is standard normal.  Then
$$\phi_X(t) = \prod_k e^{a_k^2 t^2/2} = \exp\Big(\frac{1}{2} t^2 \sum_k a_k^2\Big).$$
This looks a lot like the Euclidean Pythagorean theorem: the distance squared between the origin and $t a_1 e_1 + t a_2 e_2 + \ldots$ is $\sum_k t^2 a_k^2$ (here $e_k$ is the $k$-th standard basis vector).
(Rademacher) $X_k$ is Rademacher, i.e., $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each.  Then $$\phi_X(t) = \prod_k \cosh(a_k t).$$
This corresponds exactly to the hyperbolic Pythagorean theorem: in a hyperbolic space (with curvature $K = -1$), first move distance $t a_1$ along a geodesic, then $t a_2$ along an orthogonal geodesic, then $t a_3$ along a geodesic orthogonal to the totally geodesic submanifold containing the first two geodesics, etc.  The $\cosh$ of the distance between the starting and ending points is exactly $\prod_k \cosh(a_k t)$.
My question: What is going on here?  Is there some reason why hyperbolic geometry seems to appear in the Rademacher case?  Can this connection be made rigorous?  Maybe this is an instance of something more general?  Maybe this is just a conincidence.
Remark: Maybe it makes more sense to look at the characteristic function instead of the MGF: in that case we get $\cos$ instead of $\cosh$, and and everything I said still holds but in spherical geometry instead.
